# ESLint CLI (global install) --fix does not working

Tags: javascript, eslint

### I have tried it for a day. Nothing changed.

I installed ESLint globally, using: `npm i -g eslint`

I initialized ESLint using `eslint --init`

> (when I trying to install eslint locally and running `./node_modules/bin/eslint --init`, it says that didn't have that command)

When I run this command: `eslint ./js/lesson_1.js`, all works

When I run this command: `eslint --fix ./js/lesson_1.js`, eslint didn't fix my file.

What have I done wrong?

(sorry for my English *_*)

Comment: ESlint can't fix all issues it finds automatically. Some are too complex or can be fixed in various ways so you have to fix those issues manually.

Comment: @rickdenhaan it doesn't fix simple issues, like "variable declared, but never used"...

Comment: No, because it doesn't know how to solve that. Sometimes the variable is safe to remove, sometimes it's a bug that you're not using it and it shouldn't be removed but it should be implemented somewhere. That is the perfect example of something you have to double-check manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm on a Vue2 + Nuxt project

In order to make use of prettier + eslint the correct way, do the following:

First, install prettier:

```
npm install --global prettier
```

Secondly, install eslint/prettier integration:

```
npm install --save-dev eslint-plugin-prettier eslint-config-prettier
```

Thirdly, make sure you add the settings to **.eslintrc.js**

```
...
extends: [
        "@nuxtjs",
        "plugin:nuxt/recommended",
        "plugin:prettier/recommended",
        "eslint:recommended",
      ],
...
```

At last, add the desired configuration in the file **.prettiercr**

```
{
  "semi": false,
  "singleQuote": false
}
```

Now you can run the following command to fix the entire project issues: (don't forget the dot at the end)

```
eslint --fix .
```